# Where does "A Very British... " come from?

Tags: etymology, phrase-usage

Quite often - particularly in the media - I see British examples of things being referred to "A Very British... " whatever it is

e.g. a documentary about the British building their first nuclear bomb was called "A Very British Bomb" - but, OK it was British in that it was made in Britain, but I couldn't see what was "very" about it... (It didn't spray tea and crumpets everywhere or anything)

I don't see it applied to other nationalities (e.g. you wouldn't really see "A Very French... " or "A Very Irish... ")

A quick google search for "A Very British" shows up loads of examples, but noticeably a book from 1982 called "A Very British Coup" - are they all spawning from that or is it just another example?

**Edit**

To clarify, I'm not just talking about the words "very British" but more the commonality of the use of "A Very British" (I'm not sure of how I'd explain - perhaps that needs another question!) almost as a title or a self-contained grouping of words.

For example: If I asked you where does the common usage of the words "Big Brother" come from, you might say George Orwell's *1984* (if not the TV show! But even there it originates with *1984*) - it has a specific use outside just a brother who's big. You probably wouldn't tell me there's nothing special about "big brother" just because a google ngram shows that "little brother" is used more than "big brother"

[N-gram, little brother, big brother](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=big+brother%2Clittle+brother&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbig%20brother%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clittle%20brother%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: It actually is an expression used also with other nationalities : https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=very+British%2Cvery+Italian%2Cvery+French%2Cvery+German&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cvery%20British%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cvery%20Italian%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cvery%20French%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cvery%20German%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Josh61 Try it capitalised and you'll see what I mean... https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=A+Very+British%2CA+Very+American%2CA+Very+French%2C+A+Very+Italian%2C+A+Very+German&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CA%20Very%20British%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CA%20Very%20American%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CA%20Very%20German%3B%2Cc0

Comment: I suggest you editit your question and make clear what you are actually looking for.

Comment: I now really want them to replace Trident with a submarine that fires tea and crumpets - 'oh look, tea and crumpets, we must be at war'

Comment: Interesting question. A cursory search of Google Books turns up examples of the phrase as early as 1833. I'm not sure why the question was closed as off-topic--it's no more off-topic than any of the many other questions about the origins of idiomatic phrases.

Answer (score 13):

I think that they are, intentionally or unintentionally, referencing that book, which was also made into a 1988 <s>BBC</s> Channel 4 TV series.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Very_British_Coup

When the coup is described as "very British", I believe that they mean "non violent and polite", compared to, for example, military coups in South America which are often very violent and disruptive.  In contrast, the "coup" of the title merely involves political machinations involving the civil service and newspapers, via a publishing magnate.

So, to describe something else as "A very British X" carries the implication that it is non-violent and relatively "gentlemanly" compared to what one might normally expect.

In the case of "A very British bomb", I agree that apart from being made in Britain, I don't think there's anything stereotypically British about it, and I don't think it really deserves the implications I refer to above: I don't see how a British nuclear bomb could be more "polite" than an American one for example.  I think it's just a bit of lazy titling.

Alternately, the phrase may actually just be taken to mean "Something happening in Britain which you wouldn't normally associate with Britain."

As an aside, the plot of the novel actually seems very similar to what is happening with Jeremy Corbyn, the head of the Labour Party, at the moment, and if Rupert Murdoch started colluding with the civil service to bring him down then it would actually mirror the plot perfectly.  We'll have to wait and see...

Comment: Interesting, but OP is asking about where the "***very***  British" expression come from, and why, apparently, it is used only with reference to British  people.

Comment: @Josh61 - yes but in particular "A Very British" as a sort of stock phrase or being reused as part of a title if you know what I mean, not just "very British". So the answer is relevant although I think it's more than just politeness...

Comment: "Very British" refers to the stereotyped idea that people have about British people. As such it may carry positive or negative nuances according to context and interpretations. And that applies to all nationalities.

Comment: They're asking specifically about the phrase about "A very British X" and I'm saying it comes from this book.

Comment: @Max Williams - I see but why and with what intentions a set phrase was used in a specific context is a POB issue.

Comment: I don't see any evidence that the phrase "a very British" is being used with anything other than its literal meaning. The ngram in [Jacinto's answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/342260/63503) makes it clear that there's nothing special about "a very British" compared to "a very [some other nationality]" and nothing much special about the timing.

Comment: I also dispute the claim that "very British" always refers to the specific attributes/stereotypes of the British that you highlight, For example, it is, as you say, nonsense to suggest that "a very British [nuclear] bomb" would be more polite than other countries' bombs. But that doesn't mean the phrase is meaningless. It could mean that the bombs were produced by a somehow typically British process, which might affect the features or performance of the weapon.

Comment: For example, American nuclear weapons are fitted with sophisticated devices to ensure they are [only used when properly authorized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permissive_Action_Link). The USSR, China and France also use this kind of device but British nuclear weapons do not have them. Presumably "the British way" is to trust that the chain of command will hold and, er, that the threat of court martial is enough to stop some rogue submarine commander starting World War III on our behalf. Or something.

Comment: @Josh61 What's POB?

Comment: @DavidRicherby I think I'd need to watch the actual "A very British bomb" TV programme to comment further.

Comment: In context of a coup "very british" has nothing to do with non-violence; more likely it refers to a veneer of civility that may exist in parliament.  There are a lot of antiquated rules and traditions about conduct in parliament for example politicians of the same party will refer to each other as "my honourable friend" and opposing party members as "the honourable gentleman/lady".  So the coup in question would be conducted, in public at least, with honour and politeness, while perhaps in private it is ruthless, full of bile and the final knife delivered with a reassuring "bad luck old chap".

Comment: In the context of a bomb, very British probably refers to the engineering practices.  In contrast to American engineering stereotype of solving problems with big money, huge factories and enormous egos the British stereotype is of one or two amateur enthusiasts working in a shed solving problems with genuine ingenuity, trial and error, a bit of luck and probably coming to within an inch of blowing-up themselves and the surrounding 5000 hectares.

Comment: Wasn't it a Channel 4 TV series, rather than BBC?

Comment: @bdsl (checks wikipedia) yes you're right!  I'll edit my answer, thanks.

Answer (score 10):

This is a [**snowclone**](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Snowclone&oldid=727924090) title format, likely inspired by the book/documentary that you and Max Williams have identified.

From the Wikipedia article linked above:

> [A] Snowclone is a neologism for a type of cliché and phrasal template
>   . . . . A typical example snowclone is . . . "X is the new Y", in
>   which "X" and "Y" may be replaced with different words or phrases . .
>   . .

In other words, someone coins a catchy phrase, and other folks latch onto it as a [MadLib](http://www.madlibs.com/) for their own purposes.

I note that this snowclone is catchy enough that it was co-opted for the brand-specific "A Very Brady X": [*A Very Brady Christmas*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Very_Brady_Christmas) actually aired in December 1988, the same year as the *A Very British Coup* television series, and has since spawned *A Very Brady Movie*, *A Very Brady Sequel*, etc.

For those who are not sure that this is "a thing": Ngram is case sensitive, so for a *title* snowclone it's important to use title case.

[image]
[(Source)](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=A%20Very%20British%2CA%20Very%20American%2CA%20Very%20French%2CA%20Very%20Brady&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CA%20Very%20British%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CA%20Very%20American%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CA%20Very%20Brady%3B%2Cc0)

I'm not sure why this particular template has caught on; possibly the order of words *sounds* in some way British. For comparison, the phrase "A very good day to you, sir!" sounds vaguely British to my (American) ear. It's also possible that the Brady version has reinforced the original, as familiarity helps the phrase just sound right.

I also note that this kind of superlative for nationalities isn't unique to this phrase; a similar, more pervasive snowclone is "All American X":

[image: DET All American vs DET Very British]
([Source 1](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=The%20All%20American%2CThe%20All%20British%2CAn%20All%20American%2CAn%20All%20British%2CThe%20Very%20American%2CThe%20Very%20British%2CA%20Very%20American%2CA%20Very%20British&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CThe%20All%20American%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CAn%20All%20American%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CA%20Very%20American%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CA%20Very%20British%3B%2Cc0)) ([Source 2](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Very%20American%2CVery%20British%2C_DET_%20All%20American%2C_DET_%20All%20British%2C_DET_%20Very%20American%2C_DET_%20Very%20British&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CVery%20American%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CVery%20British%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C_DET_%20All%20American%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C_DET_%20All%20British%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C_DET_%20Very%20American%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C_DET_%20Very%20British%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2CVery%20American%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2CVery%20British%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2C_DET_%20All%20American%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2C_DET_%20All%20British%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2C_DET_%20Very%20American%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2C_DET_%20Very%20British%3B%2Cc1))

Comment: If you look closer at the "All American" it is not representative of the case. http://googlebooks.byu.edu/?c=us&q=49536826 A lot of the ngrams do not refer to constructions as the OP describes. Starting wit a company name in the Top 3 and the "All American youth something" towering on top with nearly no uses in the OP's sense.

Comment: @Helmar, I'm not sure what you mean. I wasn't saying that it was an identical snowclone to "A Very British", just that it is an example of a set phrase of the form [superlative][nationality], which maybe suggests that this is a useful thing. Of course, "All American" is used in many more contexts than "A Very British" or "very British", but I suspect it would often be preferred over "very American" in places where you would see "very British" rather than "all British". Thus in a Google search, "an all American war" > "a very British war" > "a very American war" > "an all British war".

Comment: I agree and it's a valid point, but it's not as common as your ngram suggests. Not by far. Have a look at my link. A lot of those hits continue like this "All American women/kids/men/dogs/people do something totally boring and unrelated to the question". Therefore your second ngram is highly misleading.

Comment: @Helmar I think you're right about the scale of the difference—it's why I only said "more pervasive" rather than "*much* more pervasive originally, as I knew it was an issue. (I did look at your link earlier, as well.) Hopefully the new charts are a little clearer about the (fairly conservative) point I was trying to make.

Comment: @1006a thanks for this, I'd not encountered "snowclone" before, it's my word of the day!

Answer (score 5):

In fact there appears to be nothing exceptional about the phrase *a very British*. Here's from [Google Books Ngram:](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20very%20British%2Ca%20very%20American%2Ca%20very%20French&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20very%20British%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20very%20American%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20very%20French%3B%2Cc0)
[image]

The earliest examples I could find are from the 1820s and 1830s:
[image]

Comment: You may be right, but it's more its use as a kind of stock phrase that I am thinking of, as opposed to a reference to something really being *very* or uniquely British.

Answer (score 5):

Apologies for such a simple observation, but this seems to clinch it in favour of your theory:

[image: ngram A Very British vs A Very British Coup]

[interactive version](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=A%20Very%20British%2CA%20Very%20British%20Coup&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CA%20Very%20British%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CA%20Very%20British%20Coup%3B%2Cc0)

Use of the phrase "A Very British" (with capitalisation) commences with use of that title (although slightly before the book's publication for some reason), and does not diversify until around the time of the TV series. So, while not all users necessarily are referencing *A Very British Coup* intentionally, so far as Google's corpus is concerned that's where it started. Before *A Very British Coup* people didn't appear to use *A Very British* at all.

To my untrained eye, the rate of climb of "a very British" seems also to increase following the TV series, but it's less blatant:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I disagree substantially with Max Williams. As jacinto points out, the phrase is used long before the 1988 show he refers to, and doesn't even show a noticeable spike after it. It's hard to understand why the title of the show would have been chosen if the phrase wasn't understandable to viewers.

Calling something 'British' can mean a number of things. A British car can be built in Britain or designed in Britain. A British athlete is a British citizen. But one of the meanings is "British in style" or "embodying qualities thought of as British". It's that meaning that is usually carried by "very British".

An athlete born in Britain is British, but if they are also load, brash and aggressive they would not be considered "very British" (since those are not qualities typically associated with Britishness). One who was understated and restrained might be.

The show "A Very British Coup" certainly reflects that. The coup in question is not only British in that it takes place in Britain, but also displays the stereotypical characteristics of Britishness. But I don't believe it is the origination of the phrase.